# Center custom bullets in UL

Tags: html, css

I have a ul and I changed the marker to the chevron_right from the google materials icons font. Problem is that the icons are not centered on the text.  I cannot figure out why.  So the question is how do I center the icon/bullet on the li text?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

li::marker {
  content: 'chevron_right';
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `::before` instead of `::marker` as a better pseudoelement for this, and center list items with flex.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}


li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li::before {
  content: 'chevron_right';
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you @flppv that worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's the Google font that your using .. I'd use a font-awesome instead.

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.0/js/all.js"></script>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>Item 1</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>Item 2</li>
  <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

More on [FONT AWESOME LIST (UL) EMLEMENT](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/icons-in-a-list)